# How I can import jApplet to jsp to communicate with servlet through Serializable data object

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, serialization, applet

I have applet class that connect to servlet using many Serializable DataObjects classes
I created three projects in Netbeans, Project 1 is  web application project  that have the servlet class and index.jsp file. Project 2 is JAVA project application that have jApplet class , and project 3 is JAVA project application that have all Serializable DataObjects classes and other java classes .

I added project 3 as jar file to project 1 and 2 to make the Data Objects classes available for servlet and jApplet.

Now I want to the jApplet class from project 2 to the index.jsp in project 1 to communicate with servlet through Serializable DataObjects.

My Question: is waht I am doing is right, if yes, how I can include the jApplet to jsp file in such away that can communicate with servlet, and how I can set the path of jApplet correctly.

The applet function that communicate with server is:
.
.
.

```
                           URLConnection connection = getServletConnection();
                                                    //connection.setUseCaches(false);
                        //   connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
                        //j    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
                              System.out.println(connection);
                //myOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                //      socketToServer.getOutputStream());
                            myOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                        connection.getOutputStream());
                            myOutputStream.writeObject(myObject);
                            myOutputStream.flush();
                            myOutputStream.close();

                            myInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

                //connection.getr

                myObject = (DataObject) myInputStream.readObject();
                            if (myObject.getMessage().equals("success")){
                                dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                                //DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                                date = new Date();

                                System.out.println(date);
                               //CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (javax.swing.JApplet).;

                               userName=  ((ExpertDataObject) myObject).getUser();
                               jPanel3.show(true);
                               undoB.setEnabled(false);
                               redoB.setEnabled(false);
                               jPanel4.hide();
                               createGUI();

                                myInputStream.close();


                           }
                           else{
                               ErrorText.setText(((ExpertDataObject) myObject).getError());
                                userText.setFocusable(true);
                                passText.setFocusable(true);
                           }

 private URLConnection getServletConnection()
    throws MalformedURLException, IOException, Exception {


            URL urlServlet=new URL("http://localhost:8080/ExpertToolAppletServlet2/Server");
    //URL urlServlet = new URL(getCodeBase(), "Server");
    URLConnection con = urlServlet.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            if (con instanceof HttpURLConnection)
            {
                ((HttpURLConnection)con).setRequestMethod("POST");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("this connection is NOT an HttpUrlConnection connection");
            }
    // konfigurieren
    con.setDoInput(true);

    con.setUseCaches(false);
             con.setDefaultUseCaches(false);


    con.setRequestProperty(
        "Content-Type","application/x-java-serialized-object");

    con.connect();
    return con;
}
```

The servlet code is:

```
  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, OntologyLoadException {
    HttpSession s = request.getSession(true);

    String contentType = "application/x-java-serialized-object";

    response.setContentType(contentType);
   //PrintWriter a = response.getWriter();
  // a.write("Arwa");
   System.out.println("I am here");
   ObjectInputStream in;
    String process;
    Statement statement;
    Statement statement1;
    Statement statement2;
    Statement statement3;
    try (InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream()) {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        try {
            myObject = (DataObject) in.readObject();
        } catch (EOFException ignore) {
            System.out.println("Here i am" +ignore);
        }  process = null;
     if (myObject!=null) {
         process= ((ExpertDataObject) myObject).getSession();
     }
     else{
         System.out.println("my object is null");
     }   SQL_Connection SC= new SQL_Connection();
        statement = SC.conn.createStatement();
        statement1 = SC.conn.createStatement();
        statement2 = SC.conn.createStatement();
        statement3 = SC.conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Message written: " + myObject.getMessage());
    }
```

And the HTML code is

```
  <applet code="experttoolappletservletclient.MainScreen"    archive="ExpertToolAppletServletClient.jar" width="600" height="480"/>
```

such that experttoolappletservletclient  is the source folder under project2 that containMainScreen jApplet, and ExpertToolAppletServletClient is project 2 name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would we know if its right or not without seeing any code?

Comment: Hi developerwjk, I just would like if the idea is right or wrong. I will update the post to include the code. Thanks

Comment: So are you getting an error or what?

Comment: Yes When I did in this way, I got experttoolappletservletclient.MainScreen not found exception error when running it in the browser (by right click on the Project 1), I have tomcat running.

Comment: And I do not see also the jApplet and servlet communicate, it seems no object received to servlet from japplet